# Printing on a winforms textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C# I want to make a winforms calculator application, but In order to show the numbers I need to print numbers on a textbox. How can I do that? My design is to use the textbox to display the numbers, but I don't see any print commands in the documents.
I checked on the mircrosoft docs and found that `print()`` doesn’t work and when I tried to use text that failed to. What command should I use and how to use it?  My textbox was added using the toolbox and not by code, so was my button. Maybe the problem is with the button?

```
public void button_click(object sender, System.EventArge e)
{
  X = 1; // One of the variables the user types in.
  TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();// Trying to make an object for textbox.
  XX = Covert.ToString(X);//TextBox only accepts strings so X was to be one...
  TextBox1.Text = XX;//Hoping this will display now it doesn’t help!
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: By 'printing' you mean 'display' ? If so, just what is the question? Note: Richttextbox != TextBox ! - Richttextbox: You can rtb.Appen(text)..

Comment: Alright I added details why is this question still closed how many details do you need?

Comment: I told you  what i'm making What's the problem my attempts at fixing it what else do you need?

Comment: And I told you to not mix up printing with displaying. you should fix your question. Also: Of course there are no 'print' commands in text- or richtextboxes. Printing is for sending stuff to a printer. You can change the Text property of a TextBox and for RTB do read the post below, as here you may want to preserve formatting. - After creating a control you must also add it to the Form's (or other container's) Controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

To display some text on a rich text box you can use property Text:

```
const string textToDisplay = "Hello World!";
this.richTextBox1.Text = textToDisplay;
```

This will show you unformatted text.

To display formatted text, use [RichTextBox.Rtf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string textWithRtfCodes = ...
this.richTextBox1.Rtf = textWithRtfCodes;
```

Usually the text with the rtf codes come from another source. Although it is possible to add the formatting codes to the text yourself, it is usually simpler to add the code as selected text and then change the properties of the selected text.

```
void AppendRedBoldText(string text)
{
    this.richTextBox1.Select(this.richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    thir.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(this.richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(this.textBox1.Text);
}
```

If you will be appending text in several fonts, colors, etc, more often, consider creating extension methods of a RichTextBox to append text in certain formats. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx).

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this.RichTextBox richTextBox,
        string text,
        Color color,
        Font font)
   {
        // don't update the RichTextBox while text is added
        richTextBox.SuspendLayout();

        // select the end of the richTextBox and append the text
        richTextBox.Select(richTextBox.TextLength, 0);
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = color
        ichTextBox.SelectionFont = font;
        richTextBox.AppendText(text);

        richTextBox.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

To make life easier: add several overloads:

```
    public static void AppendText(this.RichTextBox richTextBox, string text)
    {
        AppendText(richTextbox, text, richTextBox.Color, richTextBox.Font);
    }

    public static void AppendText(this.RichTextBox richTextBox, string text,
        Color color)
    {
        AppendText(richTextbox, text, color, richTextBox.Font);
    }

    public static void AppendText(this.RichTextBox richTextBox, string text,
        Font font)
    {
        AppendText(richTextbox, text, richTextBox.Color, font);
    }

    public static void AppendText(this.RichTextBox richTextBox, string text,
        FontStyle fontStyle)
    {
        AppendText(richTextbox, text, richTextBox.Color, 
           new Font(richTextBox.Font, fontStyle));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RichTextBox rtb = ...
rtb.AppendText("Hello", FontStyle.Italic);
rtb.AppendText("World", Color.Red);
rtb.AppendText("!", FontStyle.Bold);
```